# How could I draw a function by dygraphs package in R?

Tags: r, dygraphs

1. I have a R plot like `plot(t<-1:1000,log(t))`,
2. How could I draw a function by `dygraph` in R?
   I have tried `dygraph(log(t))`, but the"dygraph" function only accept the xts object(Time series data), how could I use the dygraph function to draw a non-Time series data?

Comment: Where is your `dygraphs` function coming from? Do you mean `dygraph`? I'm confused you say you have a plot in R but then you are asking how to "draw" the plot in R? What exactly is your question here?

Comment: sorry, I mean dygraph in dygraphs package. I am trying draw a plot in R by dygraph function. But the dygraph function only can draw xts object. Could I draw a non-Time series data by dygraph function？

Comment: I don't think it can. It's especially made for timeseries. Take a look at this http://ramnathv.github.io/rCharts/ similar functionalities. But why not create a xts object?

Comment: Ok,Thanks a lot. I found that recharts and plotly packages could instead it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really wanted to plot log(t) using `dygraphs` package (even though it is especially made for time series), you could do the following:

```
library(dygraphs)
x <- log(t)
time.series.x <- ts(x)
dygraph(time.series.x)
```